# How to make an AI bot of Natural Language Processing?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, opennlp

I want to make AI bot which can understand only 4 words "Up", "Down", "Left", "Right".

as my friend make a python script which executes some task by the voice like to open youtube just say "Youtube" and Chrome browser will open with youtube.com URL. But the system was slow as they were using google assistant/ai to process the voice which makes me feel impatient.

Then I got an idea what if an AI system offline which Understand only a few words and we can get some desired result and will be super fast.

for example:- I have a remote control car I want to make voice-activated as when I say "Up" car should move forward, similarly for "Down" -> Backward, "Left" -> Left and "Right" -> Right & "{Any other voice}" -> blink the led to tell that the system didn't understand

so, please someone help me.

how should i start?
how should i train the AI Bot?
what should be my requirements?
and other thing that i should know.

Thank You.

Comment: Please try to narrow down your problem, and look at [ask]. The question in its current state is way too broad to be answered here.

Comment: What does this topic have to do with programming or development? I think you should use another site on the Stack Exchange network for these questions. See [All Sites - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and maybe [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

how should you start:  reading ;-) Or I would recommend to take the coursera course on deep neural network. Your question is extremely generic.

An ad-hoc approach -- which should work on your problem -- could be to extract the audio spectrum from samples which are long enough to contain your words but not much longer. With these information you can train a convolutional neural network -- I would try 1d convolution first.